# Assign a list to a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So, what I'm trying to do is something like:

```
If(something)
   List=List2;
```

Where List can be any list (with or without args in it), and List2 is a List with Lists inside.

But in `Prolog`, I can't use the `is` statement, I can't use the `=`.
How should I do it?

Thanks in advance!!
I'm using SWI-Prolog.

Comment: In prolog variables can only be assigned once, you cannot do List=List2 if both the arguments are already initialized and not equal, = has the semantic of unification in prolog. You need to be more specific what kind of behaviour you want, do you want to reassign a value to the variable List? That is not possible in prolog, you have to create a new variable.

Comment: You cannot do exactly what you're asking for. Prolog doesn't "assign" values to variables as in other languages. You can unify an uninstantiated variable with an instantiated one and, thus, have the effet of "assigning", as in `List = List2` if `List2` is `[a,b,c]`, and `List` was unbound, then `List` will be bound to `[a,b,c]` after the unification.

Comment: It is difficult to guess what you mean, maybe you can show a query and its result on the toplevel, otherwise it is difficult to guess what you are trying to do otherwise because you are not showing what you put in and what comes out.